# Select and compare every element in a column-list

Tags: python, list

**I am trying to solve this puzzle question:** 
There is only one five-digit number *n*, such that every one of the following ten numbers share exactly one digit in common in the same position as *n*. Find *n*.

**I'm trying to get like this:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hufIc.jpg

For each column, selects every element and compares it along the column if it matches the same number. And then, appends it to get which number were matched on every column.

should i add if's in here:

```
L = [[0, 1, 2, 6, 5],
 [1, 2, 1, 7, 1],
 [2, 3, 2, 5, 7],
 [3, 4, 5, 4, 8],
 [4, 5, 9, 7, 0],
 [5, 6, 2, 3, 6],
 [6, 7, 3, 2, 4],
 [7, 8, 0, 8, 4],
 [8, 9, 8, 7, 2],
 [9, 9, 4, 1, 4]]

 for c in range(10):
     for r in range(5):
         print(L[c][r], end=' ')
 print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to get all the values of a column in a variable and then check if any value occurs more than once. The solution would look something like:

```
L = [
    [0, 1, 2, 6, 5],
    [1, 2, 1, 7, 1],
    [2, 3, 2, 5, 7],
    [3, 4, 5, 4, 8],
    [4, 5, 9, 7, 0],
    [5, 6, 2, 3, 6],
    [6, 7, 3, 2, 4],
    [7, 8, 0, 8, 4],
    [8, 9, 8, 7, 2],
    [9, 9, 4, 1, 4]
    ]

for r in range(5):
    val = [L[c][r] for c in range(10)]
    for i in range(10):
        if val[i] in val[:i]:
            print(val[i], end=" ")
            break
    else:
        print(0, end=" ")
print()
```

Comment: this is the simplest code but gonna absorb first the logic lol thankss

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [
    [0, 1, 2, 6, 5],
    [1, 2, 1, 7, 1],
    [2, 3, 2, 5, 7],
    [3, 4, 5, 4, 8],
    [4, 5, 9, 7, 0],
    [5, 6, 2, 3, 6],
    [6, 7, 3, 2, 4],
    [7, 8, 0, 8, 4],
    [8, 9, 8, 7, 2],
    [9, 9, 4, 1, 4]
    ]

for col_index in range(5):
    col= [row[col_index] for row in L]
    duplicate = [x for x in col if col.count(x) > 1]
    if len(duplicate) == 0:
        print(0, end=" ")
    else:
        print(duplicate[0], end=" ")
print()
```